# unit test for a function that returns nothing

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jestjs

I want to write a unit test for the loadingTime function. This function converts timeTable (type map) into a result array which consists of 0 and 1. Index 3-5 (03:00 - 05:00), 12-14 (12:00 - 14:00) are 1, the rest is 0. Then the result array is assigned to the rowTable. How to write a unit test for this?

```
timeTable: Map<number, Array<from: string to: string>>

0:[{from: "03:00", to: 05:00"}, {from: "12:00", to:"14:00"}]
1:[{from: "00:00", to: "23:00"}]
2:[{from: "00:00", to: "23:00"}]
3:[{from: "00:00", to: "23:00"}]
4:[{from: "00:00", to: "23:00"}]
5:[{from: "00:00", to: "23:00"}]
6:[{from: "00:00", to: "23:00"}]
```

rowTable:

```
 rowTable: Row[] = [
    { name: this.allDays.monday, items: new Array(24).fill(1), active: true },
    { name: this.allDays.tuesday, items: new Array(24).fill(1), active: true },
    { name: this.allDays.wednesday, items: new Array(24).fill(1), active: true },
    { name: this.allDays.thursday, items: new Array(24).fill(1), active: true },
    { name: this.allDays.friday, items: new Array(24).fill(1), active: true },
    { name: this.allDays.saturday, items: new Array(24).fill(1), active: true },
    { name: this.allDays.sunday, items: new Array(24).fill(1), active: true }
  ];
```

loadingTime

```
loadingTime(): void {
   if (this.timeTable) {
     let result = [...this.timeTable].reduce((r, [key, value], i) => {
       r[i] = Array(24).fill(0);
       value.forEach(o => {
         let start = getHours(o.from);
         const end = getHours(o.to);
         while (start <= end) {
           r[i][start] = 1;
           start++;
         }
       })
       return r;
     }, []);
 
     this.rowTable.forEach((el, i) => {
       el.items = result[i];
       el.active = false;
     })
   }
 }
```

my attempts, but I don't know if I'm going in the right direction. Please help

```
it("should loading Time"), () => {

  const timetableMock = new Map<number, Array<from: string to: string>>()
      timetableMock.set(0, [{ from: '00:00', to: '23:00' }]);

  component.loadingTime = () => {};

  const onSaveSpy = spyOn(component, "loadingTime")

  component.loadingTime();

  expect(onSaveSpy).toEqual([........I don't know what to enter here]);

}
```

Comment: you can't check the returned values. but you can check if `getHours` has been called.

Comment: Test the _behaviour_. What should the user see? Don't mock parts of the thing that you're supposed to be testing - your test currently makes absolutely no sense because you replace the method with a no-op implementation, then spy on that implementation, then call the spy and assert that... the spy got called? How is the real implementation involved at all?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Will something like this work?

```js
it('loadingTime should not update rowTable if timeTable is undefined', () => {
  const rowTableForEachSpy = jest.spyOn(component.rowTable, 'forEach');
  component.timeTable = void 0;
  component.loadingTime();
  expect(rowTableForEachSpy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  // in addition you can most probably assert `component.rowTable` value here
})

it('loadingTime should update rowTable if timeTable is defined', () => {
  const rowTableForEachSpy = jest.spyOn(component.rowTable, 'forEach');
  component.timeTable = new Map(...);
  component.loadingTime();
  expect(rowTableForEachSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  // in addition you can most probably assert `component.rowTable` value here
})
```

Comment: I have error: TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'timeTable')

Comment: In which context? You have not shared the full code of your component or spec. This error means that timeTable is undefined and you're trying to set its properties. Why the variable is undefined? Is your component strongly typed? If you declare like in your example `timeTable: Map<number, Array<from: string to: string>>` (i.e. without initializing the value of the timeTable), it should be `timeTable?: Map<number, Array<from: string to: string>>`.